# Vega.js - Is there a way to apply autosize to individual groups?

Tags: charts, vega

I'm using Vega 3.x —

Is there a way to apply auto-sizing properties to just a single group? Take a look at the following example:

```
   {
      "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v3.0.json",
      "width": 500,
      "height": 300,
      "data": [
        {
          "name": "table",
          "values": [
            {"category":"Long Cagtegory A", "position":0, "value":0.1},
            {"category":"Long Cagtegory A", "position":1, "value":0.6},
            {"category":"Extra Super Long Cagtegory B", "position":0, "value":0.7},
            {"category":"Extra Super Long Cagtegory B", "position":1, "value":0.2}
          ]
        }
      ],

      "scales": [
        {
          "name": "yscale",
          "type": "band",
          "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "category"},
          "range": "height",
          "padding": 0.2
        },
        {
          "name": "xscale",
          "type": "linear",
          "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "value"},
          "range": "width",
          "round": true,
          "zero": true,
          "nice": true
        },
        {
          "name": "color",
          "type": "ordinal",
          "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "position"},
          "range": {"scheme": "category20"}
        }
      ],
      "axes": [
        {"orient": "left", "scale": "yscale", "tickSize": 0, "labelPadding": 4, "zindex": 1},
        {"orient": "bottom", "scale": "xscale"}
      ],
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "text",
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "text": {
                "value": "Lorem Ipsum"
              },
              "fontSize": {
                "value": 20
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "group",

          "from": {
            "facet": {
              "data": "table",
              "name": "facet",
              "groupby": "category"
            }
          },

          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "y": {"scale": "yscale", "field": "category"}
            }
          },

          "signals": [
            {"name": "height", "update": "bandwidth('yscale')"}
          ],

          "scales": [
            {
              "name": "pos",
              "type": "band",
              "range": "height",
              "domain": {"data": "facet", "field": "position"}
            }
          ],

          "marks": [
            {
              "name": "bars",
              "from": {"data": "facet"},
              "type": "rect",
              "encode": {
                "enter": {
                  "y": {"scale": "pos", "field": "position"},
                  "height": {"scale": "pos", "band": 1},
                  "x": {"scale": "xscale", "field": "value"},
                  "x2": {"scale": "xscale", "value": 0},
                  "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "position"}
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "type": "text",
              "from": {"data": "bars"},
              "encode": {
                "enter": {
                  "x": {"field": "x2", "offset": -5},
                  "y": {"field": "y", "offset": {"field": "height", "mult": 0.5}},
                  "fill": {"value": "white"},
                  "align": {"value": "right"},
                  "baseline": {"value": "middle"},
                  "text": {"field": "datum.value"}
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

This yields something like:

[image]

I need to push the "Lorem Ipsum" text over to the left, instead of being aligned with chart area to the right of the axis. I understand there is a `title` attribute, but I can't use that because I have more complex marks that need to be in the header section that I haven't shown here for brevity.

I've also tried putting the axis properties within a wrapper group as a sibling to the Lorem Ipsum text mark group, but that doesn't seem to help either.